# PHP. Как сделать переход на главную страницу со страницы входа, при правильном вводе логина и пароля?

Tags: php

Сейчас выполняется проверка, через echo() при правильном вводе логина и пароля появляется ссылка на главную. Как через PHP автоматом при правильном вводе логина и пароля, перенаправлять на главную?

```
<?php
    require 'connect.php';
    if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $result = mysql_query("select * from users WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'", $link) or die (mysql_error($link));
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($count==true){
        $_SESSION['username']= $username;
    } else {
        echo "<div class='error'>Логин или пароль введен не правильно!</div>";
     }
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        $truefalse = 1;
        $username=$_SESSION['username'];
        echo "<div class='uspex'>Успешная авторизация</div><a href='index.html' class='uspex'>На главную</a>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Вы хоть код прикрепите...

Comment: Прикрепил код php

Answer (score 0):

header('Location: ссылка на главную')

Comment: Вставлять после проверки?

Comment: да, нужно относительный путь к главной

Comment: Как понять "относительный путь"? Можешь написать маленький код?

Comment: относительный **никогда** не надо писать

Comment: header('Location: /main.php')